# Proxy SMTP server with instructions receiving from API

Tags: proxy, smtp, postfix-mta

The task is to build SMTP proxy gateway which will send all letters to API for some checks and dependently of API answer will send letter to destination server or will return error message to client.

[Please look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxpSV.png)

IMAP will be organized in same way, all letters will be sent to API for virus checking etc. and only letters with successfull API response will be received to mailbox.

Want to ask and advice which software will be better to use for this purpose. Dovecot/Postfix? But how to integrate it with AMQP API? Maybe better will be to organize it through nginx proxy? Or python Twisted framework?

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Postfix content filter, perhaps using amavis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a COTS software solution, Forum Sentry API Security Gateway software version can act both as an SMTP proxy or an AMQP proxy.

http://www.forumsys.com/forum-sentry-secure-amqp-proxy/

[I work for Forum Systems]